# How can I map a single Row in Cassandra's Java Object-mapping API

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I have a single `com.datastax.driver.core.Row`. I have a mapper class for this specific type of rows. How can I map the Row to my mapper class?

I need `com.datastax.driver.mapping.Result.map(Row)`, however that function is private and non-static. Is there any other way?

Comment: Can't you provide a `ResultSet` instead of `Row`object ? Because the `Mapper` class has a method `map(ResultSet resultSet)`

Comment: It will not [page asynchronously](https://datastax.github.io/java-driver/manual/async/#async-paging) as far as I can see. And I don't think I can easily create a ResultSet out of a Row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest creating a JIRA ticket to ask them to make the method public. Otherwise you can use **[Achilles](http://www.achilles.io)**, it offers exactly this mapping feature on a single `Row`:

https://github.com/doanduyhai/Achilles/wiki/Manager-API#other-methods

`public ENTITY mapFromRow(Row row)`: map a given instance of `com.datastax.driver.core.Row` to an instance of `ENTITY`

Comment: Hopefully the [JIRA ticket](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1157) would help.